# How to extend disk space using LVM?

Tags: lvm

I am new to LVM so please excuse any silly questions. I created a VM on VMWare and edited the settings to extend the disk space from 40 to 80GB. Later i realized that i need to use LVM to actually extend the disk space. Since my output of `df -h` still shows 40GB.

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              396M  5.7M  390M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--prod--vg-root   38G  2.5G   34G   7% /
tmpfs                              2.0G   68K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                          720M  109M  575M  16% /boot
tmpfs                              396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1001
```

So, currently when i run `fdisk -l`, this is my output :-

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x34a96e3a

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  1499135  1497088  731M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1501182 83884031 82382850 39.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1501184 83884031 82382848 39.3G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--prod--vg-root: 38.3 GiB, 41150316544 bytes, 80371712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--prod--vg-swap_1: 980 MiB, 1027604480 bytes, 2007040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

and `sudo pvdisplay` shows the following option :-

```
--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               ubuntu-prod-vg
  PV Size               39.28 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              10056
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          10056
  PV UUID               lUfzd9-1BVL-0XGA-YJPI-Roxe-Vb7p-Wdstfb
```

So i have a couple of questions.

1. Am i understanding it right that /dev/sda5 is currently part of the volume group that is in use?
2. If /dev/sda5 in infact in use, the does it mean i would need to add /dev/sda2 to the volume group to get the desired disk space?
3. When i try to run `sudo pvcreate /dev/sda2` i am running into `Device /dev/sda2 not found (or ignored by filtering).`

So how can i extend the disk space? what am i doing wrong and what would be the right approach? Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize both `sda2` and `sda5` first using `fdisk` or `parted`. `sda2` is an [extended partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151968/what-does-the-term-extended-partition-mean-is-it-safe-to-use-this-type-of-par), `sda5` (which is your PV) is a logical partition "inside" `sda2` so you need to resize `sda2` first and then `sda5`.

After you resize the partitions you need to use `pvresize` to resize the PV format. `pvresize /dev/sda2` will be enough, without the size argument it will resize the PV to the size of the partition.

After that you just need to resize your `root` logical volume with `lvresize --resizefs -L+100%FREE ubuntu-prod-vg/root`.

As always when working with storage, make sure to backup your data first.

Comment: Thank you and can you please point me as to how should i go about resizing using fdisk?